# Grub2 physical boot selector or restart into

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub, grub2

I am using Grub2 to select between Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I was wondering how I might be able to communicate with Grub2 with a physical switch to tell it which I want. I have plenty of experience with arduino type electronics, is there some way to communicate the state of a switch through a serial to USB connection? Or is there something even more straight forward like say the parallel heads on my motherboard?

Additionally is there a way to have a shortcut on each system that tells the computer to restart and writes to a file that I want it to default boot into the other system. Then when Grub boots up it sees it, clears that file or whatever then boots into that system?

Comment: For your second question, from Linux, try `sudo grub-reboot "Microsoft Windows 7"` (http://askubuntu.com/q/635205/24107) Did you ever find an easy physical switch solution? Would love to have one myself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know , Grub2 is almost an OS. You can write yourself a module that does exactly what you want. A good guide can be found [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/49901786/GRUB2-Modules).